# Why does QtCreator 5.1.1 for android not work after reboot?

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator, reboot, qt5.1

I am able to install and configure QtCreator 5.1.1 for Android on my Windows machine. (I can't use Qt 5.2 due to MouseArea / PinchArea bug). I am than able to create a QtWidgets project with QtDeclarative as main window and lots of QML Code. Everything builds fine for both Desktop and Android...
...until I come to work the next day.

I'm not sure wether it has something to do with QtCreator restart, or system restart, but something gets wrong. Desktop build still works fine and program runs. However android build fails with following message:

```
08:25:17: Running steps for project atest4...
08:25:17: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
08:25:17: Starting: "mingw32-make" 
qtcreator_ctrlc_stub: Command line failed: mingw32-make
08:25:17: The process "mingw32-make" exited with code -1.
Error while building/deploying project atest4 (kit: Android dla arm (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.1.1))
When executing step 'Make'
08:25:17: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

When I go to project options It says "mingw32-make not found in the environment". All options for sdk, ndk, ant and others on that page seem to be in order.

Reinstallation of Qt 5.1.1 helps until the next day.

Comment: Please paste the error output in _English_.

Comment: Sorry. I thoght all the relevant lines were already in english and I didn't know how to change language in QtCreator. But I managed it now.